# Javascript - ignore a specific error in sentry

Tags: javascript, sentry

I want to ignore the following error(I have copied it from Sentry).

```
TypeError HTMLElement.handleUnpreparedAnnotatable(app-sidebar/app-sidebar-core)

Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

I can have used the following, but it **does not work**.

```
ignoreErrors: [
        /HTMLElement.handleUnpreparedAnnotatable\(app-sidebar\/app-sidebar-core\)/,
              ],
```

I can not use error's message (`Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null`) because it is not unique. And there are other errors that have the same message.

#### ignoreErrors

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/ab7ba810a97a2acae3dbd2c82b07e3972147bb97/packages/browser/examples/app.js#L38